# failed to compile React projects

Tags: reactjs

I am busy with a project of React and
When I want run a browser I get this error.

`./src/Components/ui/icons.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './src/Resources/images/logos/manchester_city_logo' in 'C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\mancity\src\Components\ui'`
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

I made sure of correct names of folders. Is it a npm webpack?

Comment: Double check the paths. The issue is related to incorrect import paths

Comment: Double check the paths. its can be case-sensitive problem

Comment: truth you all  right

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably referring to a non-existed media file or using wrong file extension when importing `manchester_city_logo` (probably in icons.js)

Doublecheck the source path for desired media file in icons.js